# How to make a process occupy one CPU completely?

Tags: linux, scheduling, real-time

I am working on an embedded Linux system (kernel-5.10.24). I am trying to make a process to occupy one CPU completely without being scheduled out.

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <sched.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int cpus = 0;
    int  i = 0;
    cpu_set_t mask;
    struct sched_param schedp;

    cpus = sysconf(_SC_NPROCESSORS_ONLN);
    printf("cpus: %d\n", cpus);

    CPU_ZERO(&mask);
    CPU_SET(1, &mask);
    if (sched_setaffinity(0, sizeof(mask), &mask) == -1) {
        printf("Set CPU affinity failue, ERROR:%s\n", strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }

    memset(&schedp, 0, sizeof(schedp));
    schedp.sched_priority = sched_get_priority_max(SCHED_FIFO);
    if (sched_setscheduler(0, SCHED_FIFO, &schedp) == -1) {
        perror("error: Failed to set the thread priority");
        return -1;
    }

    while(1)
       ;

    return 0;
}
```

I bind the SCHED_FIFO (priority 99) to the CPU1.
I also `sysctl -w kernel.sched_rt_runtime_us=1000000`.
When I check `/proc/sched_debug` and `/proc/PIDxxx/status` I found the RT process is still being scheduled, `nonvoluntary_ctxt_switches` is increased.

So how can I make a process to occupy a CPU completely without being scheduled?

Comment: Is it necessary to run your process with Linux at all? The typical approach would be to hide the second CPU from Linux, run your process as a bare metal application with an RTOS on the other CPU and establish some inter-processor communication to share data with the Linux system.

Comment: This is just for testing and helping understanding Linux scheduler.  Years ago I worked on MIPS64 project, where there were 16 cores, and developer can configure which cores can run Linux, which cores would run non-Linux system. There was a shared memory (and APIs) used as IPC. In virtualized Linux system, to get performance as good as bare-metal, some CPUs are put into `isolcpus` in kernel command line, and are used to run real-time workloads, by Linux scheduler.

Answer (score 0):

I found one way to make a process to occupy a CPU completely without being scheduled out.
In addition to what I did in the question, I also set `isolcpus=1 rcu_nocbs=1 nosoftlockup` in kernel command line.
With it, the `nonvoluntary_ctxt_switches` of the process is not changed.

I am not sure my way is a good way to do it, I found there are kernel log to say something like

```
[  271.620046] BUG: workqueue lockup - pool cpus=1 node=0 flags=0x0 nice=0 stuck for 219s!
[  271.620083] Showing busy workqueues and worker pools:
[  271.620088] workqueue events: flags=0x0
[  271.620093]   pwq 2: cpus=1 node=0 flags=0x0 nice=0 active=1/256 refcnt=2
[  271.620110]     pending: cache_reap
```

are there any other better ways?